# "Can't connect to this network" troubleshooting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, connection

After much research and testing of other answers found on SuperUser and online I cannot resolve:

- All the devices that I'm connecting to my router are
  connecting/working normally, except one PC.
- These devices include 3 android phones, 1 MacBook, 1 PC Laptop and
  two Android tablets. All working without any problems whatsoever.
- The PC that won't connect won't even touch the router and it really
  pisses me off that I can't solve it.
- I've tried with the winsock reset, driver updates, tried with a wifi
  dongle, no dice.

### Log Output

```
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Connection started 2  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Begin Connect API   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state Disconnected, event Cmd_Connect     
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Calling MSMSecStopSecurity  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({0ddb0198-3602-4de5-a5f5-e0826970c91e}) Received StopSecurity  
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]Reset PHY New MAC address 0x*MyMAC* SetDefaultMIB=true   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: Disconnected to State: Reset  
[Microsoft-Windows-WiFiNetworkManager]WlanMgr - Recieved wlan notif: wlan_notification_acm_profile_change   
[Microsoft-Windows-WiFiNetworkManager]NotifMgr - Publishing new WNF connection state, type = WIFI_NOTIF_TYPE_AVAILABLE , state = 0x0, ntStatus = 0x0.  
[Microsoft-Windows-WiFiNetworkManager]NotifMgr - Publishing new WNF connection state, type = WIFI_NOTIF_TYPE_CONNECTION , state = 0x1, ntStatus = 0x0.   
[Microsoft-Windows-WiFiNetworkManager]NotifMgr - Publishing new WNF connection state, type = WIFI_NOTIF_TYPE_PREFERRED , state = 0x0, ntStatus = 0x0.  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Scan completion Status 0  
[Microsoft-Windows-WiFiNetworkManager]WlanMgr - Recieved wlan notif: wlan_notification_acm_scan_complete  
[Microsoft-Windows-WiFiNetworkManager]WlanMgr - Recieved wlan notif: wlan_notification_acm_scan_list_refresh  
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]OID_DOT11_RESET_REQUEST Complete 0x0 ResetConfirmStatus=0x0  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state Reset , event Reset_Success  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]SSID = xxx BSSIDCount = 0   
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]Desired SSID List 1 entries   
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]Set DesiredBSSType: infrastructure  
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]Set HiddenNetworkEnabled (false): 0x0   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: Reset to State: Ihv_Configuring  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state Ihv_Configuring , event IHV_Pre_Security_Success  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Calling MSMSecPerformPreAssociateSecurity   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({0ddb0198-3602-4de5-a5f5-e0826970c91e}) MSM Connect notification, Network "xxx"   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]WLAN Security Settings: BSS Type  infrastructure , Authentication Open , Encryption WEP , OneX Enabled No , Eap Information - Type 0, Vendor ID 0, Vendor Type 0, Author ID 0  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({0ddb0198-3602-4de5-a5f5-e0826970c91e}) IntfSecState Transition INITIALIZED -->PROCESSING_PREASSOCIATE  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: Ihv_Configuring  to State: Configuring  
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]Enabled AuthList 1 entries  
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]Set ExcludeUnencrypted (true): 0x0   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Default Key: Idx 0, Algo WEP , Direction= Both , Len x  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Default Key ID set to Index 0  
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]IOCTL function=0xD4 Status=0xC0000010 Length=688 bytes 
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({0ddb0198-3602-4de5-a5f5-e0826970c91e}) IntfSecState Transition PROCESSING_PREASSOCIATE -->PREASSOCIATE_DONE
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter(5) Connect Completion, Reason 0, Error 0  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Security PreConnect Completion, security reason: 0x0, error 0x0   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state Configuring , event Pre_Security_Success  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Wireless network association started. Network Adapter: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter  Interface GUID: {0ddb0198-3602-4de5-a5f5-e0826970c91e}  Local MAC Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  Network SSID: xxx  BSS Type: Infrastructure  Authentication: Open  Encryption: WEP  802.1X Enabled: No    
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]Security endpoint type = Standard Security  
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]IHV Serialization Enabled: false   
[Microsoft-Windows-WiFiNetworkManager]AutoConnect - ConfigureAutoConnectNetworksInternal: Confirmation Timer - TimeLeft = [0] msecs    
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]IOCTL_DOT11_CONNECT   
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]OID_DOT11_CONNECT_REQUEST completes 0x0   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: Configuring  to State: Associating  
[Microsoft-Windows-WiFiNetworkManager]NotifMgr - Publishing new WNF connection state, type = WIFI_NOTIF_TYPE_AVAILABLE , state = 0x0, ntStatus = 0x0.   
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]Connection Started   
[Microsoft-Windows-NWiFi]Connection Completion Status=0xC000023C   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state Associating , event **Upcall_Association_Failure**  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Calling MSMSecStopSecurity   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({0ddb0198-3602-4de5-a5f5-e0826970c91e}) Received StopSecurity   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({0ddb0198-3602-4de5-a5f5-e0826970c91e}) IntfSecState Transition PREASSOCIATE_DONE -->STOPPING_SECURITY  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received Security Packet: CONNECT_COMPLETION   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received CONNECT COMPLETION, status 0xC000023C, assocStatus 0x2   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({0ddb0198-3602-4de5-a5f5-e0826970c91e}) IntfSecState Transition STOPPING_SECURITY -->INITIALIZED    
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({0ddb0198-3602-4de5-a5f5-e0826970c91e}) MSM Disconnect notification   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Connect completion reason 0x38002, session 0x1, **adhoc formed false**   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: Associating  to State: Disconnected  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Connection complete on interface Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter, session = 0x1, status = 0x38002, **ad hoc network formed = false**   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]**Connect Diagnostic Information  Interface** GUID: {0ddb0198-3602-4de5-a5f5-e0826970c91e}  Network Adapter: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter Connection Mode: profile   SSID: xxx  BSS Type: infrastructure  Authentication: Open   Encryption: WEP   802.1X Enabled: 0  IHV Bitmap: 5  Hidden: false  Peer MAC: 00:00:00:00:00:00  WLAN Status  Code: 229378  Dot11 Status Code: 0x2  Assoc Time: 4294967295  Assoc Restart Count: 0  Auth Time: 0  Auth Restart Count: 0  Device ID: PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_0032&SUBSYS_2C971A3B&REV_01\4&AE113B&0&0020  Device Manufacturer: Qualcomm Atheros Communications Inc.  Driver Service: athr  Driver Version: 3.0.2.201  Driver Date: 2-27-2016  RSSI: -68  Signal Quality: 62%  Channel: 0  Interfering AP Count: 0  Total Visible AP Count: 9  Max AP Phy Type: any  Max AP Channel Width: 0  AP Description:   AP Manufacturer:   AP Model Name:   AP Model Number:  Detailed Status On Roam: 0xFFFFFFFFRx Rate:0  Tx Rate: 0  EAP Type: -1 802.1x Auth Mode: None  HotSpot 2.0: false  Profile Type -1  System MAC Randomization: 1  Profile MAC Randomization: 0   
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Connection failed. Interface = Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter, Reason code = 0x38002.    
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Media notification received. Interface = Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter, Connected = false.  
[Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]WLAN AutoConfig service failed to connect to a wireless network. Network Adapter: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter Interface GUID: {0ddb0198-3602-4de5-a5f5-e0826970c91e}  Connection Mode: Manual connection with a profile  Profile Name: xxx  SSID: xxx BSS Type: Infrastructure  **Failure Reason:The specific network is not available.  RSSI: 255**
```

### Issue

- So, everything seems to go OK, but then system seems to lose the
  sight of the router even though the signal is super strong (RSSI:
  255) and refuses to continue the connection.

### What Works

- All the other devices work perfectly normal and there's no reason to suspect that router has any problems. At the same time, laptop connects to any other network also without any problems.

There just seems to be some particular hating between these two. The problem is not system related since I'm running dual boot with Win 7 and Win 10 and the situation is identical.

Comment: I am also stuck at almost the same level now. The `Upcall_Association_Failure` that you encountered accompanies a completion status of 0xc000023c, for which I found further information [here](http://joyasystems.com/list-of-ntstatus-codes) being STATUS_NETWORK_UNREACHABLE. A tiny bit more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking into your logs, it seems that your RSSI is -68 (which is good).  It also seems that you are using WEP as a security mechanism.  Some newer wireless drivers no longer support WEP as mandated by the Wi-Fi Alliance.  Please change your security to WPA2-PSK and see if your laptop associates to the Access Point (or in your words, the router).  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: So, I've played a bit with the security settings, and WEP is not a problem if it's "Open System" but there's a problem if it's "Shared Key", as it is set. Why Windows don't want to convert the password into the shared key is beyond me.

Comment: Edit: I could mark the question as solved but it's not really. Let's say I take my computer with me and I find myself half a way around the world (in some hostel) in the same situation where I can't connect because the security is set to WEP-SharedKey and the clerk doesn't have the access to the router settings (hypothetically). I would like it to work with this settings (WEP-SharedKey) as well if possible, but in my particular case switching to WEP-OpenSystem solved the problem.

Comment: Edit 2: I failed to say that the first mentioned PC Laptop runs Ubuntu. It seems that this is Windows only problem. I was able to confirm this using my friend's computer (running Win10) which also won't connect . When I ran "netsh wlan show profile WiFi-name key=clear" I've noticed that pass is stored as a hex and not as an ASCII. I guess this is what causes the problem. Is there a way to fix this in Windows?

Comment: @curious cat, no. and why would you want to? WEP can be hacked in a matter of seconds, it's a joke. You are asking to be hacked by using it. That's why nothing supports it anymore. If you find yourself in some hostel half way sound the world using WEP, I would at the very least use a VPN if you MUST connect to a vunerable access point. You are welcoming trouble if you do not...

Comment: @Tim, WEP can be hacked in a matter of minutes if there's high traffic and you have a working injection but without a Shared Kay you can't associate and therefore the injection will fail (might be wrong). If you are just sniffing the traffic it would take hours if there's not a lot of thing going on on the network. But even if the network is hacked, as I see from my own example no one using Windows can access it. As for the VPN it's a good practice whether you are using a secure or unsecured connection, especially if you travel a lot and you use public WiFi

Comment: @curious cat, wrong sir. There are three attacks that I know of that need no traffic or clients associated at all. Fragmentation attacks can recover a valid key-stream. With that you can forge your own packets to use against the router. If your using a script, it's literally seconds... Agreed on using VPNs. But, you must know, when you are connected to a vunerable wlan, someone may still be able to wage digital warefare. Don't forget a firewall.

Comment: I agree with @Tim_Stewart on this.  WEP "open" and "shared" can easily be hacked, try to make use of VPN on any sub-secure wireless network.  Here is the article where the WiFi Alliance banned the use of WEP on new Access Points beyond 2013.  https://www.zdnet.com/article/wi-fi-alliance-to-dump-wep-and-tkip-not-soon-enough/

Comment: @Tim_Stewart: From my experiments with my modem, you need at least 10-15000 IVs for a 64 bit encription, and sometimes more than a 100000 for 256 bit. It just takes time. Not long but not a few seconds as well. I've tried the attacks on my router without traffic without any success whatsoever. If you would be so kind to PM me the scripts I would like to test them.
For the both of you (and anyone else reading) - does this mean that there is no way for a Windows client to connect to a WEP-SharedKey router or not?

Comment: @pythonian: I know about this one, it was a good day for the WiFi security

Comment: @curious cat. Sorry I don't share my custom pentesting scripts. (Hint : use multiple interfaces. I might change my mind with an offer of dodgecoin.) or you can try Using wifite from Kali rolling. While I don't doubt you have tested this for yourself. I do doubt you have built custom machines for the task. It wasn't an exaggeration. It's seconds guy.

Comment: @curious cat, It's sad to say. But there are not only people still using it. Some of them have no idea it's insecure, they are doing it so people without technical aptitude don't get a false sense of security. I agree it should warn you, and let you choose just as it does with public WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting blue screens, even occasionally? I had the same trouble, router would not connect, occasional blue screens. One day I had a HDD fail. Getting that HDD out of the system eliminated the blue screens, my router connected, and the PC booted up and shut down a lot quicker. Just a thought.

You might want to run HDD diagnostics. A basic smart drive info tester is available free from Western Digital. Here is the link. You need to click software for windows, then click Data Lifeguard Diagnostic for Windows. I know there are more advanced programs for this but I don't know where they are offhand. Hope this helps.

https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en#firmware

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of searching, looking through logs I gave up and called tech support.
He just enabled random hardware addresses in Windows WiFi settings and it worked[image: ![this trick has worked for me]