Windows 11 "can't connect to this network" to some WiFi
I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 3 with Windows 11 Pro that started to no be able to connect to some WIfi networks where before it could, and that includes my iPhone hotspot.
It can connect to an Ubiquiti AP and to a Xiaomi phone in hotspot mode.
I tried to investigate the issue with the information in the Internet and nothing seems to fixed:

the usual ipconfig /flushdns and netsh winsock reset did nothing
removeing the device and reinstalling did nothing
adding the profile manually and then try to connect did nothing

I did a trace in the wifi connection attemp but I cant figure what is the problem.
This is the trace of the iPhone connection:
177445 [1]0F4C.2E38::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246865300 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: 9(Reset) to State: 8(Ihv_Configuring)
177447 [1]0F4C.2E38::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246874500 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state 8(Ihv_Configuring), event 11(IHV_Pre_Security_Success)
177449 [1]0F4C.2E38::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246885200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Calling MSMSecPerformPreAssociateSecurity
177454 [1]0F4C.2E38::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246896800 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}) MSM Connect notification, Network "iPhone do Eduardo"
177456 [1]0F4C.2E38::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246899400 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]WLAN Security Settings: BSS Type 1(infrastructure), Authentication 9(WPA3 SAE), Encryption 4(CCMP), OneX Enabled 0(No), Eap Information - Type 0, Vendor ID 0, Vendor Type 0, Author ID 0
177466 [1]0F4C.2E38::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246925300 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}) IntfSecState Transition 1(INITIALIZED) --> 2(PROCESSING_PREASSOCIATE)
177469 [1]0F4C.2E38::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246936400 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: 8(Ihv_Configuring) to State: 1(Configuring)
177476 [4]0F4C.1F98::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246951000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
177480 [13]0F4C.2E84::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246959000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}) IntfSecState Transition 2(PROCESSING_PREASSOCIATE) --> 7(WAIT_FOR_UI_RESPONSE)
177489 [2]0F4C.1490::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246968600 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Sending UI request to MSM (0)
177502 [2]0F4C.1490::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246976200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]UI interaction requested 1
177505 [2]0F4C.1490::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246977800 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]UI interaction requested 2
177509 [2]0F4C.1490::2024/09/16-19:24:12.246979100 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]UI interaction requested 3
178614 [13]0F4C.2FCC::2024/09/16-19:24:12.248260500 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
178617 [12]0F4C.5688::2024/09/16-19:24:12.248277900 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
178625 [3]0F4C.0AB8::2024/09/16-19:24:12.248296100 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
178647 [7]0F4C.2B8C::2024/09/16-19:24:12.248320300 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
178655 [1]0F4C.1F98::2024/09/16-19:24:12.248339300 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
178679 [10]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:12.248362900 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
178710 [14]0F4C.5DE8::2024/09/16-19:24:12.248390600 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
178738 [2]0F4C.53A4::2024/09/16-19:24:12.248417500 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
179073 [4]0F4C.510C::2024/09/16-19:24:12.249007200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
179267 [9]0F4C.2B8C::2024/09/16-19:24:12.249274200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
179347 [10]0F4C.5688::2024/09/16-19:24:12.249519000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
180003 [2]0F4C.2B8C::2024/09/16-19:24:12.252011100 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
180553 [11]0F4C.510C::2024/09/16-19:24:12.254615000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]UI request for interface Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter result = true.
190599 [4]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.545976900 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]UI Response - Valid = true, Cancelled = false
190610 [4]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.545981600 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]UI Response - Valid = true, Cancelled = false
190612 [4]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.545992500 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]UI Response - Valid = true, Cancelled = false
190616 [4]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.545995600 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}) UI Response, request type 2(security), response type 1(passphrase), cancelled = false
190621 [4]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.546000200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received UI response 1(passphrase)
190624 [4]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.546324500 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}) IntfSecState Transition 7(WAIT_FOR_UI_RESPONSE) --> 2(PROCESSING_PREASSOCIATE)
191097 [4]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.547017000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}) IntfSecState Transition 2(PROCESSING_PREASSOCIATE) --> 3(PREASSOCIATE_DONE)
191101 [4]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.547043400 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter(6) Connect Completion, Reason 0, Error 0
191104 [4]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.547045700 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Security PreConnect Completion, security reason: 0x0, error 0x0
191106 [4]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.547050800 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state 1(Configuring), event 10(Pre_Security_Success)
191110 [4]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.547062900 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Wireless network association started.    Network Adapter: Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter  Interface GUID: {49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}  Local MAC Address: E0:0A:F6:70:AD:13  Network SSID: iPhone do Eduardo  BSS Type: Infrastructure  Authentication: WPA3-Personal  Encryption: AES-CCMP  802.1X Enabled: 0(No)  
191327 [0]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:14.548044800 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: 1(Configuring) to State: 2(Associating)
194278 [9]0F4C.53A4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.300421900 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received Security Packet: 9(CONNECT_COMPLETION)
194281 [9]0F4C.53A4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.300425000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received CONNECT COMPLETION, status 0xC000023C, assocStatus 0x1000001
194288 [9]0F4C.53A4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.300445500 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state 2(Associating), event 3(Upcall_Association_Failure)
194294 [5]0F4C.53A4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.300555800 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Calling MSMSecStopSecurity
194297 [5]0F4C.53A4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.300571100 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}) Received StopSecurity
194316 [14]0F4C.53A4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.300873000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}) IntfSecState Transition 3(PREASSOCIATE_DONE) --> 4(STOPPING_SECURITY)
194347 [14]0F4C.53A4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.300915000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}) IntfSecState Transition 4(STOPPING_SECURITY) --> 1(INITIALIZED)
194351 [14]0F4C.53A4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.300917700 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}) MSM Disconnect notification
194370 [14]0F4C.53A4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.300939800 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Connect completion reason 0x38014, session 0xC, adhoc formed false
194382 [14]0F4C.53A4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.300964200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: 2(Associating) to State: 0(Disconnected)
194657 [7]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.301694600 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Diagnostic Statistics Difference  Interface GUID: {49a6b3ea-9b63-4be9-b323-0b6191c866b7}  Event: 2(AssociationFailure)  MacTxUnicastCount: 0  MacRxUnicastCount: 0  MacRxMulticastCount: 0  MacRxUnicastDecryptSuccess: 0  MacRxUnicastDecryptFailure: 0  PhyTxFailedCount: 0  PhyTxFrameCount: 0  PhyTxRetryCount: 0  PhyRxFrameCount: 0  PhyRxFcsErrorCount: 0  TimeDiffMs: 1  
194692 [7]0F4C.3FF4::2024/09/16-19:24:17.301708700 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Change session to 0xD. Interface = Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter.

And this is the trace for a successful Ubiquiti AP connection:
26888 [9]0FB8.292C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.033370000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: 9(Reset) to State: 8(Ihv_Configuring)
26895 [9]0FB8.292C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.033390600 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state 8(Ihv_Configuring), event 11(IHV_Pre_Security_Success)
26900 [9]0FB8.292C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.033416800 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Calling MSMSecPerformPreAssociateSecurity
26913 [9]0FB8.292C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.033827200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({70f18e8f-a1d6-4d10-9629-f010d3e29cf3}) MSM Connect notification, Network "NovaFarmacia"
26920 [9]0FB8.292C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.033829900 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]WLAN Security Settings: BSS Type 1(infrastructure), Authentication 7(RSNA PSK), Encryption 4(CCMP), OneX Enabled 0(No), Eap Information - Type 0, Vendor ID 0, Vendor Type 0, Author ID 0
27217 [3]0FB8.292C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.090470800 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({70f18e8f-a1d6-4d10-9629-f010d3e29cf3}) IntfSecState Transition 1(INITIALIZED) --> 2(PROCESSING_PREASSOCIATE)
27224 [3]0FB8.292C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.090492100 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: 8(Ihv_Configuring) to State: 1(Configuring)
27754 [5]0FB8.1A8C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.091824400 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({70f18e8f-a1d6-4d10-9629-f010d3e29cf3}) IntfSecState Transition 2(PROCESSING_PREASSOCIATE) --> 3(PREASSOCIATE_DONE)
27757 [5]0FB8.1A8C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.091838500 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter(1) Connect Completion, Reason 0, Error 0
27760 [5]0FB8.1A8C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.091840600 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Security PreConnect Completion, security reason: 0x0, error 0x0
27762 [5]0FB8.1A8C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.091845400 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state 1(Configuring), event 10(Pre_Security_Success)
27766 [5]0FB8.1A8C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.091859000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Wireless network association started.    Network Adapter: Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter  Interface GUID: {70f18e8f-a1d6-4d10-9629-f010d3e29cf3}  Local MAC Address: E0:0A:F6:70:AD:13  Network SSID: NovaFarmacia  BSS Type: Infrastructure  Authentication: WPA2-Personal  Encryption: AES-CCMP  802.1X Enabled: 0(No)  
27774 [2]0FB8.5B2C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.091943200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 18
28073 [0]0FB8.1A8C::2024/09/16-21:58:32.102263300 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: 1(Configuring) to State: 2(Associating)
31546 [1]0FB8.292C::2024/09/16-21:58:34.259644800 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 18
31778 [11]0FB8.292C::2024/09/16-21:58:34.260511200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 18
31901 [1]0FB8.5B2C::2024/09/16-21:58:34.260791900 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 18
31938 [4]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:34.260894500 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 18
32117 [11]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:34.261461900 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 18
32304 [11]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:34.262010000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 18
35239 [5]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:35.213832200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received Security Packet: 37(ASSOCIATION_COMPLETED)
36692 [1]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:38.056202400 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received Security Packet: 37(ASSOCIATION_COMPLETED)
36714 [1]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:38.056319600 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received Security Packet: 0(PORT_UP)
36721 [1]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:38.056337800 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state 2(Associating), event 4(Upcall_Port_Up)
36727 [1]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:38.056371100 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Wireless network association succeeded.    Network Adapter: Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter  Interface GUID: {70f18e8f-a1d6-4d10-9629-f010d3e29cf3}  Local MAC Address: E0:0A:F6:70:AD:13  Network SSID: NovaFarmacia  BSS Type: Infrastructure  Management Frame Protection Enabled: 0x400000000  
36742 [1]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:38.056389200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Wireless security started.    Network Adapter: Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter  Interface GUID: {70f18e8f-a1d6-4d10-9629-f010d3e29cf3}  Local MAC Address: E0:0A:F6:70:AD:13  Network SSID: NovaFarmacia  BSS Type: Infrastructure  Authentication: WPA2-Personal  Encryption: AES-CCMP  FIPS Mode: 0(Disabled)  802.1x Enabled: 0(No)  
36746 [1]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:38.056398600 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({70f18e8f-a1d6-4d10-9629-f010d3e29cf3}) Port up for peer 0xF09FC274A6A5
38547 [2]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:38.063651300 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({70f18e8f-a1d6-4d10-9629-f010d3e29cf3}) IntfSecState Transition 3(PREASSOCIATE_DONE) --> 5(PROCESSING_POSTASSOCIATE)
38586 [2]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064076900 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Adapter({70f18e8f-a1d6-4d10-9629-f010d3e29cf3}) IntfSecState Transition 5(PROCESSING_POSTASSOCIATE) --> 3(PREASSOCIATE_DONE)
38600 [2]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064101700 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Transition from State: 2(Associating) to State: 4(Authenticating)
38602 [7]0FB8.292C::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064168200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Number of Unique Wlan Networks 19
38605 [3]0FB8.5934::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064174700 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received Security Packet: 9(CONNECT_COMPLETION)
38607 [3]0FB8.5934::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064175500 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received CONNECT COMPLETION, status 0x0, assocStatus 0x0
38610 [3]0FB8.5934::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064181000 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FSM Current state 4(Authenticating), event 2(Upcall_Association_Success)
38619 [4]0FB8.1BD8::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064201400 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received Security Packet: 32(LINK_STATE)
38639 [3]0FB8.5934::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064226400 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Received Security Packet: 8(LINK_QUALITY)
38650 [3]0FB8.5934::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064238200 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Link Quality: 100
38679 [7]0FB8.292C::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064270100 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Scan completion Status 0
38682 [2]0FB8.5B2C::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064270600 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]FAST ROAMING is 1
38694 [2]0FB8.5B2C::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064274800 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Port(1) Peer 0xF09FC274A6A5 SecMgr Transition 1(INACTIVE) --> 2(ACTIVE)
38710 [2]0FB8.5B2C::2024/09/16-21:58:38.064283500 [Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig]Port(1) Peer 0xF09FC274A6A5 SecMgr Transition 2(ACTIVE) --> 3(START_AUTH)

Any help is appreciated, I don't want to reinstall my Windows machine

When I have random issues connecting to wireless networks that are not resolved by updating drivers, forgetting wireless networks, etc, I will download the latest available wireless drivers, delete the wireless radio from the Device Manager and choose to uninstall the driver when prompted, then restart and install the updated drivers.

The issue occurs at the lines Received CONNECT COMPLETION, status 0xC000023C, followed by FSM Current state 2(Associating), event 3(Upcall_Association_Failure) [as opposed to `4(Upcall_Association_Success) in the other log]. See https://superuser.com/questions/1314342/cant-connect-to-this-network-troubleshooting for a similar issue.

Details about the AP you cannot connect to?

@Ramhound The AP at work I don't know what is, but the same happens with the iphone hotspot.

@DrMoishePippik Thanks but I already read that article and there is no solution for the problem.

What WiFi standard? Edit your question

@Ramhound The Ubiquiti AP that I can connect to is Wifi 5, the iphone is a 13 so I think is using 802.11ax (Wi-Fi 6), at least is what I found on the internet.

I am not interested in what you CAN connect to, I am interested, in what you CANNOT connect to. In an ideal world you would also indicate what WiFI the client was using also.

@Ramhound So on the client side is Windows 11 using Realtek 8852AE so I presume it will try to use Wifi 6, I don't have a Wifi6 AP that I can test against only the iphone hotspot.
If this is not enough please tell me what/how to get the info and I'll share it. Thanks for all the help

@EduardoReis - I don't believe the iPhone supports hotspot functionality over Wi-Fi 6. What version of Windows 11? Wi-Fi 6 was only recently added to Windows 11. Only recent iPhones even support Wi-Fi 6.  You have not supplied any information with regards to the access point you are unable to connect to

@Ramhound About the AP that I can't connect is the one one the office and I don't have access to it, is there a way to get info from an AP just from what it broadcasts?

@EduardoReis - Ask somebody with the knowlege the specificatons of the access point.  Have you asked somebody in your office for assistance.  It might be a problem with the access point not the client.

@Ramhound I asked, but there are no support in-house, and also I'm the only one that can't connect to the Wifi. Until the end of August I could and don't remember to do anything to my PC that could prevent the connection but could happen.
Next time I'm in the office I'll try to gather more info.

My suggestion is have your System Administrator reimage your device.
